My Australia 600 denied, it states”the applicant did not satisfy the provisions of the Migration 1994
Im a filipino, permanently living in japan and married to a japanese National, my first time to apply visa and travel aside from philippines and japan, but it was denied, i dont translate the papers i attached bcoz i dont know if it is required, how can i reapply and be granted the 2nd time around? Me and my husband wants to go to Cains for relaxation for 7 days only

The applicant did not satisfy the provisions of the Migration Regulations 1994. The attached decision record provides detailed information about this decision as it applies to this applicant. Review rights There is no right of merits review for this decision. Receiving this letter As this letter was sent by email, you are taken to have received it at the end of the day it was transmitted. Questions about this decision We cannot consider your visa application any further…. from The immigration


I think you tried to include the full reason in the title, but it was truncated. Please edit your question (using the “edit” link below the question) to add the full reason given.

The applicant did not satisfy the provisions of the Migration Regulations 1994.
The attached decision record provides detailed information about this decision as it applies to this applicant.
Review rights
There is no right of merits review for this decision.
Receiving this letter
As this letter was sent by email, you are taken to have received it at the end of the day it was transmitted.
Questions about this decision
We cannot consider your visa application any further…. from The immigration

Press the 'Edit' link and add whatever else that is stated in your letter of refusal.

We need the contents of the “attached decision record” (with all personal info removed of course).

That’s a very broad refusal reason. Check the refusal letter to see if it gives any other reasons. Before reapplying, read this help guide  which you will see clearly states:

Include as much information as possible to support your application. This includes English translations of your documents.

You can also search on TSE via the tag [Australia] to find questions about visa refusals.

The applicant did not satisfy the provisions of the Migration Regulations 1994.
The attached decision record provides detailed information about this decision as it applies to this applicant.
Review rights
There is no right of merits review for this decision.
Receiving this letter
As this letter was sent by email, you are taken to have received it at the end of the day it was transmitted.
Questions about this decision
We cannot consider your visa application any further.

@アナ永 It sounds like you should look at the attached decision record.

If you don't provide an English translation of the documents that's going to be an automatic refusal. The officer probably isn't going to even bother looking at other elements. Apply again with translations of the documents and see what happens.

I have already read the description of refusal, it seems that my explanations needs to be more specific and compact
